# Generate random text in word with a specified number of words

Tags: microsoft-word

I am starting to use more powerful tools in MS-Word such as the `=rand(p,l)`. What I want to do is instead of doing `=rand(paragraphs,lines)` I would like it to generate a certain number of words like so `=function(words)`. How would it be possible to do this?